# Is it possible to set up a map of my Minecraft server I can access outside of minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I was wondering if it's possible to get a map of my Minecraft server which would show a updated version of everything on my Minecraft sever which I would be able to access whilst I'm not on Minecraft.

If this is possible, is it then possible to have an interactive map?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a plugin called [Dynmap](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1543523-dynmap-dynamic-web-based-maps-for-minecraft/) which gives you an interface which is similar to Google Maps. It updates in near-realtime, can show player icons running around on the map, and lets you zoom in and out, and pan around.

Comment: Note: This needs Bukkit, Spout of Forge server; a vanilla one won't work.

Comment: if it needs Bukkit, would that mean that it could work with Tekkit, or have i got my mods mixed up?

Comment: Tekkit is an completely different launcher then minecraft. You can see bukkit as an extension for 'vanilla' minecraft.

Comment: @Elliott If it works with bukkit, it *should* work with Tekkit, since tekkit uses bukkit underlying (based on the answer of marco Geertsma )